# No instance of overloaded function matches the argument list

Tags: c

**Errors:**

```
E0304   no instance of overloaded function "strstr" matches the argument 
list    testtranslator  
E0304   no instance of overloaded function "strstr" matches the argument 
list    testtranslator  
E0167   argument of type "const char **" is incompatible with parameter of 
type "const char *" testtranslator
C2665   'strstr': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument 
types   testtranslator  
C2665   'strstr': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument 
types   testtranslator  
C2664   'size_t strlen(const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const 
char *[2]' to 'const char *'
```

I'm very new to programming, but I have to code this English - French text translator due the day after tomorrow.
It has to replace the words with the given words or phrases... My text is the following "Hello", "What" and "How are you?" and I need to translate it into "Salut", "Comment vas-tu?"
I have no idea how to handle the errors and I would be truly thankful for some help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What compiler are you using? A C++ compiler or a C compiler for this C code?

Comment: There are no overloaded functions iin C. You are using a compiler for a wrong language.

Comment: I've been using Visual Studio!

Comment: Visual Studio is not a compiler. It's an IDE. You are using a compiler for a wrong language.

Comment: It was using the C++ compiler from the IDE instead of the one for C. I am sorry, I've changed it now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass `const char**` as a `word` parameter, while I guess your idea was to pass `const char*`. Looks like you need to choose particular word from `word` array, like following:

```
strstr(string, word[0])
```

because you have declared it recently as:

```
const char *word[] = {
    "hello", 
    "what"
};
```

And, by the way, rename `word` to `words` and that would probably stop you from further confusing.

Comment: Thank you! It works as expected now! I do appreciate a lot!